# import nested json into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

**JSON STR:**

```
{
"PurchaseId": "Pur-001",
"Orders": [{
    "id": "154",
    "isOnline": false,
    "Store_location": {
        "Order-Date": "2019-06-04T07:35:00"
    },
    "Store_Network": [{
        "Network_Domain": "Food_Processing"
    }]
}],
"Sales": [{
    "id": "1856",
    "SalesLoads": [
        1000,
        3000,
        5000
    ],
    "Network": [{
        "id": "London_Store",
        "history": [
            0,
            1,
            2,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Leads": {
            "From": "Mgmt-Dept",
            "time": "34hrs"
        }
    }]
}]
```

}

**Expected Dataframe:**
[image]

**My code so far:**

```
import pandas.io.json as pd_json
data = pd_json.loads(json_str)
df=pd_json.json_normalize(data, record_path='loads')
```

I've tried JSON_Normalize but unable to load this JSON string into dataframe. Is it possible to do it using JSON Normalize or is there any other optimized solution available.

Comment: json validator gives "Invalid JSON" on your json string

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I got it fixed. Updated the question with valid JSON .

Comment: unfortunately, I get `_recursive_extract(obj[path[0]], path[1:],
TypeError: string indices must be integers` in the middle of `json_normalize `

Comment: No problem..Thanks for all your help. I will look for some work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty long, but gets the job done. Hopefully someone answers with a better solution and less verbose.

```
a = {
"PurchaseId": "Pur-001",
"Orders": [{
    "id": "154",
    "isOnline": False,
    "Store_location": {
        "Order-Date": "2019-06-04T07:35:00"
    },
    "Store_Network": [{
    "Network_Domain": "Food_Processing"
}]
}],
"Sales": [{
    "id": "1856",
    "SalesLoads": [
    1000,
    3000,
    5000
],
"Network": [{
    "id": "London_Store",
    "history": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "Leads": {
        "From": "Mgmt-Dept",
        "time": "34hrs"
    }
}]
}]}

b = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a)


b = (b.assign(Orders_id = b.Orders[0]['id'],
              Orders_isOnline = b.Orders[0]['isOnline'],
              Orders_Store_Location_Number = pd.to_datetime(b.Orders[0]['Store_location']['Order-Date'].split('T')[0])
                                               .strftime('%m/%d/%Y'),
              Orders_Store_Network_Domain = b.Orders[0]['Store_Network'][0]['Network_Domain'],
              Sales_id = b.Sales[0]['id'],
              Sales_Load = [b.Sales[0]['SalesLoads']],
              Sales_Network_id = b.Sales[0]['Network'][0]['id'],
              Sales_Network_history = [b.Sales[0]['Network'][0]['history']],
              Sales_Leads_from = b.Sales[0]['Network'][0]['Leads']['From'],
              Sales_Lead_Time = b.Sales[0]['Network'][0]['Leads']['time']                                                    
            )
      .drop(['Orders','Sales'],axis=1)
     )

b
```